# how to automatically set value of textbox according to value of another textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I had `textbox1`, `textbox2`, and `textbox3` I want to automatically set value of `textbox2` and `textbox3` according to value of `textbox1` which has an auto complete method as below...

what should I do within the while clause to automatically set value of `textbox2` and `textbox3` after finishing auto complete at textbox1 ??

I am working on these error form two days everything is public within my code... I have one think i am wondering about is that new class should be defined within the namespace scope like `namespace { Class class_name}` but I am defining the class instead of another class like  `name spaces {class Class_name1 {classs Class_name2 } }`  but my problem is that when i put my class within the name spaces scope I am getting alot of error and it wont recognize a lot of key words ... so please would tha be the problem ?? and if yes please can you lead me to solve this ???

public class PopulateProduct
        {
            public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
            public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        }

```
    Dictionary<string, PopulateProduct> dict = new Dictionary<string, PopulateProduct>();

    public void load()
    {
        string connstr = "user id=rawpic;password=admin";
        string cmdtxt = @"select PRODUCT_ID,DESCRIPTION,UNIT_PRICE 
                              from products";

        AutoCompleteStringCollection autocom = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocom;

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    dict.Add((string)dr["PRODUCT_ID"],
                        new PopulateProduct()
                        {
                            ProductDesc = (string)dr["DESCRIPTION"],
                            UnitPrice = (decimal)dr["UNIT_PRICE"]
                        });
                    autocom.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }


    private void TB_PRODUCT_ID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text)) 
        {
            TB_PRODUCTS_DESC.Text = dict[TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text].ProductDesc;
            TB_UNIT_PRICE.Text = dict[TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text].UnitPrice.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this `WinForm` TextBox?

Comment: If its all on UI thread, then just set the property Textbox.Text, else on a separate thread, you still need to access the UI thread, or it will throw exception, since the UI objects cannot be modified from other threads

Comment: @Ian yes it windows form

Comment: @Mrinal Kamboj actually I have privilege problem I don't know why the error message says.. 'RAWPIC.RP0102.Object.ProductDesc' is inaccessible due to its protection level 
'RAWPIC.RP0102.Object.UnitPrice' is inaccessible due to its protection level
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,RAWPIC.RP0102.Object>.Add(string, RAWPIC.RP0102.Object)' has some invalid arguments 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'  is that related to what you say about thread ??? if yes then can you help me ?

Comment: @Mrinal Kamboj I had post the full code if that will help

Comment: These are compilation errors not runtime, where ever its the protection level make it public to get it working and in object to string, typecast object as string, assuming genuinely string inside

Comment: I am working on these error form two days everything is public within my code... I have one think i am wondering about is that new class should be defined within the `namespace scope` like `namespace { Class class_name}` but I am defining the class instead of another class like ' name spaces {class Class_name1 {classs Class_name2 } } ' but my problem is that when i put my class within the name spaces scope I am getting alot of error and it wont recognize a lot of key words ... so please would tha be the problem ?? and if yes please can you lead me to solve this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"...everything is public within my code..."*

Please check again. Properties of your `Object` model is not public yet (and `Object` is not a good name for your model ... how about `Product` ?) :

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Regarding the last part of the error message, that's because `DataReader["column_name"]` returns object. You need to explicitly cast the result to suitable type :

```
dict.Add((string)dr["PRODUCT_ID"], 
         new Product() 
         { 
            ProductDesc = (string)dr["DESCRIPTION"], 
            UnitPrice = (decimal)dr["UNIT_PRICE"]
         });
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help could you please take a look at using that at text change event is that correct ?

Comment: @ har07 I solved the problem but now nothing happen no suggestion appears and nothing happen I tried to remove (4 sure that is wrong ) the if part but its trow exception that says The given key was not present in the dictionary. ... i have update my original post with all change.. i am working on that form two says it new way I want know it